# How to copy code to the Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibeacon

I'm following this guide, However the guide says to SSH to copy the scripts over but I can't do this on my halls internet or my uni's. I was wondering how I can get the code onto my Raspberry Pi.

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/09/how-to-make-an-ibeacon-out-of-a-raspberry-pi.html

(The bit from step 10 - 14)

Sam

Comment: So you can't ssh - what CAN you do at you uni? Don't let us guess. What about sending it by email to a dedicated account?

Comment: Please direct rapsberry pi questions to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com for the future

Comment: I find it really hard to believe that a university would block SSH.

Comment: Obtain a hub or router and connect both your PC and the pi to it; DO NOT connect this to the university network if doing so is prohibited.  Or, run linux (or a linux filesystem driver) on your machine, shut down the pi, connect it's SDcard to the PC and copy files.  Or use a USB memory stick to move files between the PC and the pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other options as well.

- FTP (check this [link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=44700) for more info)
- On the device itself (so you bassicly create your scripts on the Pi itself by connecting to it using SSH) like they explain in your link.
- Depending on the IDE you are using (on your PC), you could do remote deploys with for example Ant.

I would go for (S)FTP is I where your.

Comment: If he can't SSH, he can't SFTP. The difference between SFTP and FTP confuses people; don't make thinks worse by bundling the two into "(S)FTP".

Comment: It's all-or-nothing with SSH. No firewall can know whether you're tunneling SCP or SFTP or a command shell through SSH.